# Вычислить число размещений из n по m

Tags: java

Нужна помощь, кто чем может,нужно реализовать функцию, которая будет вычислять количество размещений из n по m , спасибо.
[image]

Comment: Даже формула неверная. И решение задачи - два метода по одной строчке в каждом, и это если длинно писать.

Answer (score 0):

```java
BigInteger a(int n, int m) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (long i = n; i >= n - m + 1; i--) {
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```